# Get the id + the map of a vertex on Gremlin?

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin

> g.v(1).id

gives me vertex 1 id,

> g.v(1).map

gives me vertex 1 properties.

But, how can I get a hash with id and propeties at the same time

Answer (score 13):

I know that it's an old question - so answers below will work on older versions of TinkerPop (3<); just if anyone (like me) stumbles upon this question and looks for a solution that works on TinkerPop 3 - the same result can be achieved by calling valueMap with 'true' argument, like this:

```
gremlin> g.v(1).valueMap(true)
```

reference may be found in docs [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#valuemap-step)

Comment: This has been deprecated. With the 3.4 release (see [Upgrade Notes](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.0/upgrade/)), you should use `gremlin> g.v(1).valueMap().with(WithOptions.tokens)`

Answer (score 4):

As of Gremlin 2.4.0 you can also do something like:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.v(1).out.map('name','age','id') 
==>{id=2, age=27, name=vadas}
==>{id=4, age=32, name=josh}
==>{id=3, age=null, name=lop}
```

Another alternative using transform():

```
gremlin> g.v(1).out.transform{[it.id,it.map()]}
==>[2, {age=27, name=vadas}]
==>[4, {age=32, name=josh}]
==>[3, {name=lop, lang=java}]
```

Answer (score 1):

if implementing with Java use

```
g.V(1).valueMap().with(WithOptions.tokens).toList()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution

```
tab = new Table()
g.v(1).as('properties').as('id').table(tab){it.id}{it.map}
tab
```

Answer (score 0):

Just extending on @Stephen's answer; to get the `id` and the `map()` output in a nice single Map for each `Vertex`, just use the [plus](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#plus(java.util.Map)) or [leftShift](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#leftShift(java.util.Map)) Map operations in the `transform` method.

**Disclaimer:** I'm using `groovy`, I haven't been able to test it in `gremlin` (I imagine it's exactly the same).

#### Groovy Code

```groovy
println "==>" + g.v(1).out.transform{[id: it.id] + it.map()}.asList()
```

or

```groovy
println "==>" + g.v(1).out.transform{[id: it.id] << it.map()}.asList()
```

#### Gives

```groovy
==>[[id:2, age:27, name:vadas], [id:4, age:32, name:josh], [id:3, name:lop, lang:java]]
```